# JMS serializer runtime exception to throw 400 status code

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I'm using JMS serializer, and have two fields, check-in and check-out as datetime with a specific format, like this:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d'>")
 * @Assert\Date()
 */
 protected $checkin;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d'>")
 * @Assert\Date()
 */
 protected $checkout;
```

Now, I want to throw a 400 HTTP status code, if for example, someone sends an invalid format (eg. empty string).

The problem is that JMS Serializer throws a `RuntimeException` when it can't create a datetime from the format in DateHandler, like this:

```
if (false === $datetime) {
    throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Invalid datetime "%s", expected format %s.', $data, $format));
}
```

This exception gives a 500 HTTP status code.

Also checked the possibility to add an exception code of 400 to the config, for this instance, but the problem is that JMS throws this type of exception in a broad range of different situations.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a situation where you would use something like [json-schema](http://json-schema.org/) ([PHP implementation](https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema)) to validate the user submitted JSON rather than relying on JMS Serializer which is, as the name would suggest, purely for de/serializing content rather than validating it.

As a stop gap you could do a try/catch around the deserialization and then manually return a 400 response, e.g.

```
try {
    $deserialized = $serializer->deserialize($content, My\Class, 'json');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return new Response($e->getMessage(), 400);
}
```

Although this would solve your immediate problem it's not really the best code path. In your example Symfony is catching the exception itself (as it's not being caught by your code) and translating that into a 500 response, JMS serializer itself cannot return a 400 response.

Comment: Good point. To use json-schema to validate, prior to deserializing content. Thanks.